# nginx simple .htm to .php rewrite rule does not work

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have this simple rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/category.htm /category.php last;
```

and it does not work and the site gives 404 error.

This is happening only on a specific server, while this rule works fine everywhere else.

**The important thing is that if I remove the dot (.) from the rule and use an underscore for eg, it works fine.**

So I think it is some issue with escaping the dot (.)

I also tried this but it does not work either:

```
rewrite ^/category\.htm /category.php last;
```

Can anyone please help!

Comment: I couldnt do that due to security reasons but this gave me the idea to look for something else that could be messing, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by emptying out the whole file and then adding it back line by line...

Thus I found out exactly where the problem was and it was an external file that was messing the rules in this file...

**My advice to everyone, if you are ever stuck in such a situation, try commenting all the includes first and then you can safely say that whatever is happening its from your code and you can fix it then**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, and I've got no way of testing it right now, but I think the period needs to be in brackets. You may also need a dollar sign. So, something like:

```
rewrite ^/category(.)htm$ /category.php last;
```

I can't promise it's the correct answer, but I'm pretty sure you're on the right track by trying to escape the period.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it does not work
I also tried like this `rewrite ^/category([\.])htm$ /category.php last;` but no luck :(

Comment: Looks like I didn't read your initial post very well! Yes, what you posted initially works for me too. Maybe post the whole config?

Comment: there was another config that was included in this config file and that was having some rules that were screwing up with my rules!
thanks for trying to help